# When getting current cart from an external file, it's empty

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, shopping-cart

I searched and was unable to find anything. I've tried many solutions such as: [How to get all items in cart currently?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/how-to-get-all-items-in-cart-currently) as far as I can tell it should work in Magento 1.8. I've tried `Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();` and `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();`

An example of something I tried:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    echo "something";
}
```

Doing print_r on `$cart` shows that `$_items` is empty and `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();` returns 0.

Full example code to clear confusion, error reporting is on:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',true);

require_once('app/Mage.php');  
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$totalItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
if( $totalItems == 0 )
{
    echo "0 items";
}

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    echo "something";
}
```

Someone will visit the magento store, add items to their basket and then click a link which takes them a PHP file. However, their basket is always empty when checked from the external file. Is there a problem with the code or the magento configuration or is the wrong way to do it in Magento 1.8?

Comment: what do u mean by external file?

Comment: Are you running Mage::app() in the file.

Comment: From an external file? The cart is of course linked to a session. Which cart items do you expect to get? You would only get cart items if you put some items in the cart in your external file beforehand.

Comment: Updated to clear things up. By 'external' file I mean a php file which someone will navigate to afterp lacing items in their basket.