# Magento send order email wihout going to checkout

Tags: checkout, cart, email

What I want to do is.

1. I need to disable the checkout process.
2. When logged-in users go to view cart page after added some products, the page will have order by email button. So when click on that button I need to send email to admin+user with order details and need to save order details at my account section.

Any idea really appreciate...

Comment: 1st question that comes to mind would be "why using Magento if you don't want people to checkout i.e. order things ?"

Comment: Using a ecommerce system has many advantages: catalog, products, prices, ... :)

Comment: Yes I agree with you.But that's what client want.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to override the checkout page and convert the sales quote into sales order programatically behind the scene with custom values like (shipping address, shipping methods, payment methods).

Then as you have overridden the checkout page with your custom template having button ***order by email***, the user will click on it and order details will be sent to the admin & customer. You need to code accordingly in your custom checkout template.

Code for this will be time-consuming, so basic overview given.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Do you   have source code to read the values from the shopping cart?

Comment: `$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}` this code snippent loads the current quote items and you can change it accordingly

Answer (score 2):

1. I would think about throwing everything into a wishlist and misuse it somehow.
2. The alternative is to just implement your own controller and send an email/fake an order to do it the real way.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Do you   have source code to read the values from the shopping cart?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/how-to-get-all-items-in-cart-currently