# why getColumnValues('product_id') not work for Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item') collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, quoteitem

I want to get all `product_ids` of `quote_items` without for loop.
 I don't use `$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();`

I want to use below code
Below code not work and it throws error.Error is Fatal error:  `Call to a member function getStoreId() on a non-object`

Why below code  not work for `getColumnValues('product_id')`  ? Any idea ?

```
$quote_id = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData('entity_id');
            $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quote_id);
            print_r($collection->getColumnValues('product_id'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by `setQuote()` function

```
    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
                ->setQuote($quote);
        print_r($collection->getColumnValues('product_id'));
```

Comment: In which context are you doing that? I mean if you are doing that around an active session, you should load the quote data from the session or singleton instead to reload the entire model.

Comment: Because I am developing split cart functionality

Answer (score 1):

Because `getAllVisibleItems()` returns an array instead of a collection. Use `Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection()` instead and apply filters as needed.

See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78325/243 for more information about the different methods to retrieve quote items.

Comment: I override getItemsCollection(Mage/sales/Model/Quote.php) method

Comment: And now it does not return the item collection anymore?

Comment: I am developing Split cart functionality so I override itemscollection method and filter by vendor so

Comment: Then you need to replicate the code from the original method.

Comment: sorry I do not understand what you say.Could you elaborate more ? I override getItemsCollection method and filter by vendor id . After successfully place vendor1 product I am adding rest of vendor product in cart programmatically

Comment: getItemsCollection() method use sales/quote_item model therefore I have used this model collection

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you override the method, you can create another method in the rewritten class with `return parent::getItemsCollection();` and use that