# Is there an event that fires when the cart/quote is empty?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer

I would like to set a quote's shipping method based on the items selected in the quote (only if there is not already a shipping method selected) and unset the quote's shipping method when there are no more items in the cart/quote.

However, I'm having difficulty with part 2 of this problem.  I have tried observing `sales_quote_address_save_before`, `sales_quote_save_after` and `checkout_cart_save_after` and they all exhibit a very odd behavior:

If I add or remove items from the cart, these events fire **twice** with the **new number** of items in the cart (so for example, if I had 1 item and added 1 item, it would fire twice with 2 items in the model).

However, if I remove all items from the cart, all three events only fire **once** with the **old number** of items in the cart (for example, if I had 1 item in the cart and delete it, the event fires once with 1 item in the model, not 0).

Is there an event that I can use to tell when I have no items in the cart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What works well for me to react on cart changes is a combination of these events:

- checkout_cart_save_after
- customer_login
- customer_logout
- checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

> However, if I remove all items from the cart, all three events only fire once with the old number of items in the cart (for example, if I had 1 item in the cart and delete it, the event fires once with 1 item in the model, not 0).

You are probably looking at the wrong data. When items are removed from the cart, the objects get a `deleted` flag but stay in the collection. If you use `$cart->getItems()` or `$cart->getItemsCollection()` these deleted items are included. Use `$cart->getQuote()->getAllItems()` or `$cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()` instead.

I explained the difference between these methods in: [How to get all items in cart currently?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/how-to-get-all-items-in-cart-currently/78325#78325)

Comment: I ended up solving my problem in a different way, but you seemed to have the most in-depth response, so you get the check.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up changing how my logic works so instead of observing adding or removing items from cart, I observe `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` and choose the default shipping method at that point based on the contents of my cart.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sales_quote_remove_item event. The removed item is passed to the observer as an argument.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_remove_item', array('quote_item' => $item));
```

Next, you just need to make sure that there are no items left in the quote. The observer method should look like this:

```
public function removeShipping(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
{
    $quote = $observer->getQuoteItem()->getQuote();

    if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
        //remove shipping
    }
}
```