# Magento 2 - Get category id of products in shopping cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I would like to get category IDs and name of products in shopping cart.

> $product = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()->getProduct();
>
> $category = $this->_category->getCategoryIds($product);

Comment: Please refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111137/magento-2-how-to-get-all-items-in-cart or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789133/get-shopping-cart-details-in-magento2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* $this->_productRepository =  \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface */
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($pid);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
var_dump($cats); die;
```