# Get cart items from shipping carrier

Tags: magento2, shipping

In my Carrier class for my custom shipping method, I have tried calling `$request->getAllItems()` as well as injecting an instance of `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` and calling `getAllItems` as well. All that is returned is an array of empty objects. No matter what I do, they are empty. I am just trying to get the items in the cart to send to our shipping rate service to calculate the rates.

I referred to this as well to guide me: [Magento 2 - How to get all items in cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111137/magento-2-how-to-get-all-items-in-cart/134082)

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange, because I can see in debug all items directly in the request, and they is not empty:

[image: example from debug]

Try to get items from the quote, like:

```
$items = $this->session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

It should work, since all items are constantly stored in the quote.

Comment: It seems that you have to call methods explicitly on the collection that is returned. Trying to var_dump() the getAllItems() result is always empty. After I iterated through the the items I was able to get methods. It seemed really odd though that I wasnt able to dump out the contents with var_dump. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: @StephenHendricks `getAllitems` returns all of the items in the cart https://gyazo.com/37d7761faef2e09ce4e669e4fc4311e9 not an empty array. Here the items has been added to the request: `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address::requestShippingRates` in line 957: `$request->setAllItems($item ? [$item] : $this->getAllItems());` and you can see how it works in the `public function getAllItems()` in the same class.

Comment: I saw how it worked, but just for some reason whenever i tried to log the contents of the result of this method, I went to json_encode() and log it, and it just serialized to an empty object is what I'm saying.

Comment: @StephenHendricks I'll try to reproduce your error, on which line you do this?

Comment: I've sense gotten around this, but I believe I was in the collectRates() method on in the shipping carrier class. I believe I had injected an instance of checkout/session and called getQuote() on that and then getAllItems on that. and I just tried to do `json_encode($this->_logger->debug($this->_session->getQuote()->getAllItems()));` or something along these lines.