# How to get checkout cart data ? Magento2

Tags: magento2

`$itemsVisible` and `$items` return 0, only `$itemsCollection` not empty, but this doesn't work in foreach , thanks for help

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

// get quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// get quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems(); 

$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

 // get quote items array
 $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

 foreach($itemsCollection as $item) {

    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: you have two $items variable that conflicts one another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 - How to get all items in cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111137/magento-2-how-to-get-all-items-in-cart)

Comment: ok, i removed  $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();, and in foreach use this $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();  but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, your cache is Enable, so you can't get values in an external file.

Once you disable the cache, it will work fine