# How can I get all data from cart

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, quote, quoteitem

Is it possible to get check if cart has any product been added in. I want to check if a product been added to the cart in a phtml page.
If the user click the page I want to show how many product they added in just the quantity 
If there is nothing show 0

Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean any logic to get cart contents. If so this should offer all the explanation you need.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/111167/70343

In addition to this you need to add a count.

So `count($block->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems())` for example

If I have misunderstood can you add more detail.

Comment: I just need to see if the user added anything to the cart. Wouldn’t this return an array? I am trying to check if the user added anything in the cart return true if not return false

Comment: if you count($empty_array) you get 0.  If you (bool) count($empty_array) you get boolean value

Comment: thank you for this I will check this and update this