# I am trying to get current quote details in an phtml

Tags: magento2, session

```
    class Productinfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {    
       protected $checkoutSession;             
       public function __construct(
          \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,  
          \Magento\Checkout\Model\SessionFactory $checkoutSession,  
           array $data = []
       )
     {
          $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;           
          parent::__construct($context, $data);
      }

     /*
      * Checkout Session Data
     */
      public function getCheckoutSession()
      {
         return $this->checkoutSession->create();
      }
    }
```

This is block file function when I use the this function it gives data of last quoteId not current when cache is on.Please help me with this

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111137/magento-2-how-to-get-all-items-in-cart

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this below code :

**Method 1 :**

```
protected $checkoutCartBlock;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,  
  \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart $checkoutCartBlock,  
   array $data = []
)
{
  $this->checkoutCartBlock = $checkoutCartBlock;           
  parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/*
* Checkout Quote Data
*/
public function getCheckoutSession()
{
 return $this->checkoutCartBlock->getQuote();
}
```

**Method 2 :**

```
protected $checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,  
  \Magento\Checkout\Model\SessionFactory $checkoutSession  
   array $data = []
)
{
  $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;           
  parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/*
* Checkout Quote Data
*/
public function getCheckoutSession()
{
 return $this->checkoutSession->create()->getQuote();
}
```

To get quote id : **`$block->getCheckoutSession()->getId();`**

**Remove generated and clean cache.**

Comment: Tried both but have to clear the cache every time to get current quote id

Comment: This things happen every time .We can't refresh the cache every time that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
protected $cart;

public function __construct(
    ..................................
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    ..................................
) {
    ..................................
    $this->cart = $cart;
    ..................................
}

public function getCartItems()
{
    $cart_data = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($cart_data as $item) {
        print_r($item);
    }
}
```

> **Call getCartItems() function into phtml file.**

Comment: Tried but have to clear the cache every time to get current quote id

Comment: try this print_r($item->debug()); this show all data.

Comment: It shows data but the cached data of  previous quote no current quote.This is something related  to FPC

Comment: have checked ? above code always return current Quote data.

Comment: This get data of previous from cache.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a custom block and you are facing an issue with cache then try something like this

```
<block class="Something\Something\Something\Class" name="blockname" template="Something_Class::something.phtml" cacheable="false" />
```

A single `cacheable="false"` will disable Full Page Caching for the whole page, making the pages sourcing from that layout file extremely slow! Check https://inviqa.com/blog/how-full-page-cache-works-magento-2

Comment: cacheable="false" is not recommended in the magento standards .

Comment: Can you provide me a source for that because I have found many places where they themself using cacheable="false"

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html