# Bundle product in quote

Tags: bundled-product, quote

Would be someone please be so kind and explained me structure of bundle products? I need to retrieve products in quote no matter if they belong to bundle or not, but if I get bundle product's item, then I see even more items than I actually have in quote. I mainly need to get product's `quantity`, `sku`, `name`, `price`, `tax rate` and `tax amount`.

I did not find suitable answer so please, do not mark question as duplicate if you do not have solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the quote, a bundle product contains:

1. one parent item with

   - qty: bundle qty
   - sku: depends on the SKU type of the bundle. If it is "fixed", this is the SKU of the bundle, if it is "dynamic" it is a combination of the bundle SKU and all selected simple product SKUs, separated by `-`
   - name: bundle name
   - price: calculated sum if the price type is "dynamic", bundle price if the price type is "fixed"
   - tax_percent: tax rate of the bundle, does not matter if price type is "dynamic"
   - tax_amount: see "price"
2. a child item for each selected simple product

   - qty: selection qty (multiply by the bundle qty to get the total qty of this item)
   - sku: simple product sku
   - name: simple product name
   - price: simple product price if the bundle price type is "dynamic", 0 if the bundle price type is "fixed" (if you configured a price for the bundle selection instead of leaving the "use default" checkbox checked, this price is used and not the price of the simple product itself)
   - tax_percent: tax rate of the simple product, does not matter if bundle price type is "fixed"
   - tax_amount: see "price"

If you want to iterate over all rows of the cart, use `$quote->getAllVisibleItems()`, for bundle products this only returns the parent item.

(see also: [How to get all items in cart currently?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/how-to-get-all-items-in-cart-currently/78325#78325))