# $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems() returning an empty array

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-collection

I am trying to get a collection of all items in the cart for current session but the array is returning [0].

My block:

```
<?php
namespace GGG\PaymentMethodsManagment\Block;
class GetProductsInCart extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_cart;    
    protected $_checkoutSession;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCart()
    {        
        return $this->_cart;
    }

    public function getCheckoutSession()
    {
        return $this->_checkoutSession;
    }

}
```

In my template file:

```
<?php
    $quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    var_dump($items);
?>
```

`var_dump($items)` is printing `array(0) { }`.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

All suggestions from the current answer:

```
<?php
    $quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();
    \Zend_Debug::dump($quote);
    $getItemsCollection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
    $itemCountgetItemsCollection = count( $getItemsCollection );
    echo "getItemsCollection():";
    \Zend_Debug::dump($itemCountgetItemsCollection);

    $getItems = $quote->getItems();
    $itemCountgetItems = count( $getItems );
    echo "getItems():";
    \Zend_Debug::dump($itemCountgetItems);

    $getAllItems = $quote->getItems();
    $itemgetAllItems = count( $getAllItems );
    echo "getAllItems():";
    \Zend_Debug::dump($itemgetAllItems);

    $getAllVisibleItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    $itemCountgetAllVisibleItems = count( $getAllVisibleItems );
    echo "getAllVisibleItems():";
    \Zend_Debug::dump($itemCountgetAllVisibleItems);

?>
```

All of the  abode return `int(0)`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should simply extend from [Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart.php).

```
<?php
namespace GGG\PaymentMethodsManagment\Block;
class GetProductsInCart extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart //\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
```

Now, you can simply call `$this->getItems()` and this should give you all the items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still can't get it to work... Can you give me a working example? :)

Comment: Can you tell me what does it return on `<?php echo get_class($block);?>` in your template file? And also how is the template file called?

Comment: It returns `GGG\PaymentMethodsManagment\Block\GetProductsInCart` also, the file is called using XML and added to content: `<block class="GGG\PaymentMethodsManagment\Block\GetProductsInCart" name="get_products_in_cart" template="GGG_PaymentMethodsManagment::get_product_in_cart.phtml" />` --------- Any solution/tutorial/guide/method would be okey for me. I am struggling for 3 days now...

Comment: Is this in your custom `URL`? and I believe you have cleared cache.

Comment: Yes, I have routes.xml file with following: `<route frontName="PaymentMethodsManagment" id="PaymentMethodsManagment">
            <module name="GGG_PaymentMethodsManagment"/>
        </route>` Also, I did clear my cache, static etc.

Comment: Got it... I don't know why but when I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/PaymentMethodsManagment/Index/` it works, but I was looking at `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/PaymentMethodsManagment/Index/Index`... Spend hours trying to figure that out.

Comment: That's great. Cheers.

Comment: I accepted your answer since you mentioned that URL might be wrong. Any ideas why this is? So I don't make the same error again?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess it is something to do with layout file and block call. For each controller file/action, we need separate xml to reference properly.

Comment: I see, I'll make a note of that, thank you kindly for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Block** `GetProductsInCart`

```
<?php
namespace GGG\PaymentMethodsManagment\Block;
class GetProductsInCart extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_cart;    
    protected $_checkoutSession;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCart()
    {        
        return $this->_cart;
    }

    public function getCheckoutSession()
    {
        return $this->_checkoutSession;
    }

}
```

**Template:**

```
<?php
    $quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();
    $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    $itemCount = count( $items );
    \Zend_Debug::dump($itemCount)
?>
```

You can retrieve the items in several ways, which is basically [the same as in Magento 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78325/243):

- ```
  $quote->getItemsCollection()
  ```

  Returns a quote item collection with *all* items associated to the current quote.
- ```
  $quote->getItems()
  ```

  This is a shortcut for the method above, but if there is no quote it returns an empty array, so you cannot rely on getting a collection instance.
- ```
  $quote->getAllItems()
  ```

  Loads the item collection, then returns an **array** of all items *which are not marked as deleted* (i.e. have been removed in the current request).
- ```
  $quote->getAllVisibleItems()
  ```

  Loads the item collection, then returns an **array** of all items *which are not marked as deleted AND do not have a parent* (i.e. you get items for bundled and configurable products but not their associated children). Each array item corresponds to a displayed row in the cart page.

Choose what fits your needs best. In most cases the last method is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, please see my updated answer. They all seem to deliver nothing... :/